# Android phone reboots on uninstall 

Tags: android, reboot

I am developing an app and when I uninstall the phone kind of semi-reboots.

This is my old post:

> I have a strange problem with my phone. I am using SAMSUNG GALAXY 5
>   (GT-I5500) with Android 2.2 on it (not rooted).
>
> I am an android developer and I have been doing pretty advanced apps.
>   However, sometimes when I am testing and installing an application the
>   phone reboots.
>
> I'm starting it trough Eclipse but I do not know what exactly what
>   causes the phone to reboot.
>
> - It is not heat for sure, as I keep my phone cool enough.
> - It is not from the app source itself as the phone doesn't reboot while I am using the application but on installing time
> - It is not storage **I think**, because I have 26 MB internal and 1GB external memory free and the app is no more than 2 MB.

So my question is what could cause the phone to reboot?

> In this context I define "reboot" as the phone showing the initial SAMSUNG screen, like normal booting but without the prompt for PIN. This is why I conclude it is something like semi-reboot or I do not exactly know.

Comment: Have you checked the phones LogCat for any hints?

Comment: Yes but I cannot find anything suspicious. No fatal errors or warnings. ( or at least none I can see)

Answer (score 2):

Having experienced the same problem, I found that deleting dalvik cache and formatting cache partition helped - I can't tell which one of those two did the trick, but I can now happily uninstall apps again, without the device spontaneously rebooting.
Both operations I was able to perform in recovery mode, using ClockWorkMod rescue system, and they are non-destructive. No actual data or apps are lost, only next reboot takes longer, due to dalvik cache being rebuilt.

Today, close to a month later, that problem showed again, so I was able to test which of those two action fixes it. Turns out it was erasing the cache. Dalvik  cache was left alone, deletion was possible afterwars nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

I have this exact problem with my LG G4. Whenever I try to uninstall an app the phone will just reboot. Luckily there is a way to remove unwanted apps if your phone has an expandable memory option through micro SD. Just transfer the unwanted app on the SD card then remove the card. The app will no longer exist on your phone. You can then just delete the app from your SD card using a PC. This doesn't help resolve the actual OS issue on your device but at least it's a quick fix for anyone who's looking to free up some space. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Spontaneous reboots under unclear conditions, one of the "fun" things you get for free with Android. Not on each and every device, OS version or combination thereof, but quite too often.

**With the following instructions you will loose all your data on your phone.**

Try this: Get into the recovery mode (`adb reboot recovery` *or* start the phone with pressing (and holding) volume down, then press and hold the center key, then power on), then `wipe data/factory reset`, `wipe cache partition`.

(I experienced similar reboots but not with an I5500, so I don't know if this will help in this situation. It helped with a Motorola Milestone/Droid after upgrading to Android 2.2.)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by wiping the davilk-cache thanks to Deleted User's experience. However, wiping the cache partition was not necessary in my case. I'm rooted stock Android 4.4.2 KitKat on a Galaxy Tab 3 SM-T210R.